# CSS is not executed in media query

Tags: css, media-queries, responsive

I am trying to make a desktop size website responsive. Just as I started, I noticed that the CSS rule is read by the browser however it is not executed regardless if the media query rule is true or not. I included the `<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />`, no change. I can not manage to find the logic of the browser and why it is not reading it.

```
div class="nav">
   <div class="logo"><a href="index.html">GETTI</a></div>
   <div class="nav-menu">
      <div class="menu-item"><a href="#">Home</a></div>
      <div class="menu-item"><a href="#">Why Choose Us</a></div>
      <div class="menu-item"><a href="#">How it works</a></div>
      <div class="menu-item"><a href="#">Teams</a></div>
      <div class="menu-item"><a href="#">Contacts</a></div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    body {
        width:100%;
    }
    .nav-menu {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

I am somehow sure that it has to do with how the normal (not responsive) CSS was written so I am going to include that as well.

```
.nav-menu {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: (20%)[auto-fill];
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 20%);
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You're expecting the `nav-menu` to disappear when the browser width is less than 768px? I tested this out using your code provided and I am seeing that behavior. Was there something you expected to happen?

Comment: Your code (media queries)  works on my computer, too.

Answer (score 2):

If the CSS rules are in the order which you posted in your question (i.e. media query first, then general rules), the general rules will *always*  overwrite the rules from the media query (because they are valid for *any*   screen size). Just change the order to avoid that: General rules first, then media queries.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Apparently , I have to write the entire nested class instead of just typing the class. Did not know that.